# why don't we use simple encryption?

Tags: encryption, lua

What i mean by this is that if i create a Lua program that randomly assigns numbers and letters to a three digit code wouldn't this code then be almost unbreakable(like if someone that wasn't supposed to got it) unless you have the program? sorry if this was already asked could some1 direct me to it.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Yeah, i'm in school currently i will update at 3ish eastern time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not programming related; it would be better for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not really a question about Lua.

Comment: Ok sorry :P i'm a noob, never used stackoverflow b4 :)

Comment: People solve ciphers like that with a pen and paper.  They are in crosswords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a called a [substitution cipher.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)

These are broken by using [frequency analysis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) Because each letter and number is always assigned to the same code, letters in the input will lead to the corresponding codes appearing in the output with the same frequency. The cryptanalyst will study the kinds of data he expects to be input to the cipher, and find common symbols and patterns, then match those with frequent patterns in the output. For example, if the input is English text, the cryptanalyst knows that the most frequent codes represent E, T, A, O, I, … and the most common sequences are "THE", "BE", "OF", "AND", etc.

Codes in the output should occur with uniform probability. When there is a bias in the output, it can be exploited to break the code. One way to avoid this, in basic terms, is to use a different "code book" for each letter in the input. So "E" doesn't always translate to the same code; it would depend on the position of the "E" in the message.

Comment: But what if you were to change the encryption codes every 24 hours?

Comment: Or maybe even every hour, then wouldn't this code be near unbreakable b/c of the computational power required to run frequency analysis?

Comment: Or possibly scramble the letters?

Comment: @Matt Substitution and transposition (one method of scrambling the letters) are parts of real ciphers like AES. The techniques you describe are good ways to show kids basic cipher ideas with paper and pencil. But they don't stand up to computerized code-breaking. If this is a toy for 4th-graders or a puzzle in a game, it could be a fun way to learn. But if you actually care about privacy in a real application, this doesn't provide any security at all. Use a real cipher, like AES.

Answer (score 1):

Simple encryption is not used because it is not sufficiently secure. We use a level of encryption necessary to meet the required security level to successfully defend against attackers.

Attackers range from a curious friend to nation states, think the NSA, GCHQ, KGB & etc.

["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.